# how to use def with parameters in python

Tags: python, function, parameters

why does it print 0 and not 5?
i cant find the error in my logic?

```
score = 0

def pass_score(test_string, aScore):
  if re.match(a, test_string):
    increase_score(5, score)
    print (aScore)

def increase_score (aValue, aScore):
  aScore += aValue
```

Answer (score 2):

First approach, without the global var, returning value:

```
def increase_score (aValue, aScore):
  aScore += aValue
  return aScore

def pass_score(test_string, aScore):
  if re.match(a, test_string):
    aScore = increase_score(5, aScore)
    print (aScore)
```

Second approach, using [global](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#index-54) var:

```
score = 0

def increase_score (aValue):  #don't need to receive score, I've it.
  global score
  score += aValue

def pass_score(test_string):
  global score
  if re.match(a, test_string):
    increase_score(5)
    print (score)
```

I guess you need a mix of both. Any case, your code looks a bit dirty at this moment, mixing local and global vars.

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING HAVE A HAPPY NEW YEAR

Answer (score 1):

You could do globals, but don't. Instead, return the value.

```
def increase_score (aValue, aScore):
    return aScore += aValue

def pass_score(test_string, aScore):
    if re.match(a, test_string):
        aScore += increase_score(5, aScore)
    print (aScore)
```